Relation between the inverse Laplace and inverse Mellin transforms
If we have the answer to the inverse Melin transformation of an expression, can we arrive at the inverse Laplace transform of that expression?
$$M^{-1}\left (\frac{1}{\Gamma (c+s)\Gamma (d-s)}  \right )=\frac{1}{\Gamma(c+d) }x^{-c}(1+x)^{c+d}$$
Is it possible to obtain the inverse Laplace transform from the expression obtained from the inverse transform of Melin? that’s mean
$$L^{-1}\left (\frac{1}{\Gamma (c+s)\Gamma (d-s)}  \right )=?$$If someone has an opinion and an idea to solve the inverse Laplace transform of the desired expression, please provide it.

Can anyone guide me?
